# NSMutableArray does not respond to objectAtIndex selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

okay, I know I am new to obj-c, but for all intents and purposes the following below SEEMS like it should work:

```
songCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [songCollection addObject:@"test"];
    //Array is init, and I can see it in the debugger.
    songCollection = [GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"];
    // I can see the expected data in the debugger after this.
    [songCollection retain];
    NSLog(@"%@", [songCollection objectAtIndex:0]);
        // Crashes here due to the array not responding to the selector. Also, the array is now empty.
    //NSLog(@"%@", songCollection);
    NSArray * songList = [songCollection objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", songList);
```

I'm hoping someone can help me here, I'm banging my head against the wall!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`songCollection` was originally an NSMutableArray, but then you overwrote it with whatever is returned from `[GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"]`.  Whatever that is, it's probably not an array.

Incidentally, you're leaking an array here.

Comment: You might want to say [songCollection addObjectsFromArray: [GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"]] instead of completely replacing the array. That line will fail it the result of the getJSONAsArray: function is not an array, and you can be 100% sure the result is still an NSMutableArray!

Comment: Here's the problem, I am telling the function getJSONAsArray to return a NSArray, however, the debugger tells me it's a NSCFDictionary object when I get it back...

Comment: And, I answered my own question with my previous response.

Fro some reason the JSON library I am using is intelligent enough to know to return a Dictionary if it can, and then fail back to Array.

Grrr...

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 7):

Lets take your code apart step by step.

```
songCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Allocates a new empty NSMutableArray.

```
[songCollection addObject:@"test"];
```

Adds the NSString @"test" to the NSMutableArray songCollection

```
songCollection = [GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"];
```

Throws away your reference to the mutable array you created (thus leaking memory) and gives you a new pointer to something that you do not own yet.

```
[songCollection retain];
```

Thats good, you take ownership of songCollection.  And since this works, you know that getJSONAsArray returned either nil or an NSObject.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [songCollection objectAtIndex:0]);
// Crashes here due to the array not responding to the selector. Also, the array is now empty.
```

So clearly songCollection is neither nil, nor an NSArray (mutable or otherwise).  Check the documentation or signature for GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray and see what it actually returns.

```
//NSLog(@"%@", songCollection);
```

What does this output - that should tell you what songCollection actually is.

Assuming you figure out why getJSONAsArray is not returning an NSArray, you can convert an NSArray to an NSMutableArray with

```
songCollection = [[GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"] mutableCopy];
// You now own songCollection
```

or

```
songCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// You now own songCollection
[songCollection addObjectsFromArray:[GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Does [GeneralFunctions getJSONAsArray:@"library"] actually return an NSArray?

You're also forgetting to release songCollection before you re-assign it with that line.